# How to alter MySQL table without losing data?

Tags: mysql, database, alter

In my application, I make some changes and upload them to a testing server. Because I have no access to the server database I run `ALTER` commands to make changes on it.

Using a method I ran the following command on server:

```
ALTER TABLE `blahblahtable` ADD COLUMN `newcolumn` INT(12) NOT NULL
```

After that, I found that the **all the data** of the table has been removed. Now the table is blank.

So I need to alter the table **without** removing his data. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide more details about what, exactly, happened?

Comment: make sure you don't convert text to integer (something like that)

Comment: please show us wich kind of alter command have you done, because i have done hundred of alter command and no data was lost.

Comment: @all of us read now. now i clear thing better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your question is quite obvious. You're adding a new column to the table, and setting it to `NOT NULL`.
To make things clearer, I will explain the reaction of the server when you run the command:

1. You add a new column, so **every row** of the table has to set a value for that column.
2. As you don't declare any *default value*, all the rows set `null` for this new column.
3. The server notices that the rows of the table have a `null` value on a column that doesn't allow `null`s. This is illegal.
4. To solve the conflict, the invalid rows are **deleted**.

There are some good fixes for this issue:

- Set a **default value** (recommended) for the column you're creating.
- Create the column **without** the `NOT NULL`, set the appropiate values, and then make the column `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp table, pass all the information from the table you want to alter, and then return the info to the altered table.

Comment: could you provide the example?