# Is there any way to import database table schema only

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I have two databases. Now I'm trying to import all table schema only from first database to second database. I already exported all table structure from first database using phpmyadmin. But I can't import the table structures in the second database. phpmyadmin says

> #1050 - Table 'XXXXXX' already exists

How can I import only the table structure correctly?

Note: Both databases had same table and all table had same structure. I have changed some table structures in the first database that I can't remember right now. Now I need to merge both table structure only. Also both database contains different data set and I can't afford any data loss from both databases.

Answer (score 2):

*Before executing any command I would recommend taking full database backup, otherwise you may lost a few days of sleep.*

### Using `ALTER` command

Use [`ALTER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) command to modify table structure. Here's sql that adds age not nullable *age* field to *users* table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE users ADD age int(11) not null
```

### Re-creating table

I wouldn't recommend this method because you'll have data loss. Drop old table then create with new schema.

```sql
DROP TABLE mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  ...
);
```

Or if you want to keep data you can:

1. Duplicate or rename table to different name.
2. Create a new table with new schema.
3. Copy data from old table: `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable`

Renaming tables might cause relationship issues. I would recommend using `ALTER` command as much as possible. You can also take a look at [scheme migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration)(aka: code first migration, database migration).

Comment: sir i want to update the table structure only as i said in the question. is there any way for batch update all table schemas. method 3 marge data only.

Comment: @EmptyBrain you must use alter method. look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5706625/7616528

Comment: Please try to understand the issue. i know i have to use alter method. it has a lot of tables with huge data. and i can't remember where i changed in the structure. for method 1 i have to search all tables for identify the changes by myself before altering table structure. As i said i already export table structures. Now what should i do for update all changes at onece

Comment: oky so you want to update the structure of a table from another table?

Comment: @sandy that's it. yes i want to update the structure of a table from another table.

Comment: oky @EmptyBrain one way is first you make a backup of a database. Then drop the database and then copy "only structure" from another database and then restore the previous data.I think this way you can do it.

Comment: you know any another way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176048/discussion-between-empty-brain-and-sandy).

Answer (score 0):

The main Issue is merging the tables. To identify the differences between the two tables I use a small software called **SQL Power Architect**.